# Do processes get slower as amount of free memory diminishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've always been under the impression that as long as you have free memory, whether its 100% or 10%, the speed of your processes should not be affected.

However, I recently ran into a situation where it seems that my processes get a lot slower when it uses up a greater percentage of the memory available.

It could be a problem with the code itself, but I'm hoping to get a quick sanity check that I haven't been living a lie before delving deeper into the code iteself.

Comment: What kind of memory in particular are you talking about? Notice that the memory your OS provides to a process is [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) only.

Comment: The primary memory “performance” issue is when the system has to start paging to disk (in a way that negatively affects performance; not all paging is bad). Using a tool to monitor paging would be a start to get an idea if the issue is more likely the result of too much memory used (causing negative paging) vs data-structures or algorithms (perhaps in conjunction with leaks) that do not scale.

Answer (score 2):

It all really depends upon how the app is coded and what it is doing.  For some apps, it won't make any difference whether free memory is 10% or 100% as long as there's enough for it to do its job.

For other apps, they may encounter memory fragmentation, they may cause disk swapping, they may even adjust their own behavior because of less available memory (using smaller buffers, forcing data to disk, etc...).  In a garbage collected system (like nodejs), a lower memory condition may cause more frequent garbage collection too.

The single biggest performance impact from running lower on memory will be if the app causes the OS to page memory to disk.  This is where the virtual memory being used exceeds the actual physical memory and the OS has to substitute some disk space for memory that is allocated.  The OS tries to swap  memory to disk that hasn't been accessed recently in the hopes that it won't be needed again soon, but sometimes that just doesn't work very efficiently and you get a lot of hard disk thrashing, constantly reading/write memory to/from disk.  Since disks are thousands of times slower than physical memory, this can massively slow things down.

There are also cases of app design where some operations in an app like Photoshop that will simply run faster with more memory available to use because the algorithms will adapt to use the larger amount of memory to make the operation run faster when working on large objects.  A nodejs app or library could be doing the same thing.  For example an image processing algorithm may be designed to work on images larger than will fit in memory so it has to decide how much memory is "safe" to allocate and then work on the image in chunks.  With a smaller amount of memory available, the work gets done less efficiently in smaller chunks.

A more common reason why things get slower over time is because of some sort of internal fragmentation or leaks that make regular housekeeping chores (like allocating memory) less efficient.  This may occur either at the heap level or at the app level.  This is why some admins schedule long running processes (like servers) to be automatically restarted every once in awhile - to clear up any of this fragmentation or small leaks and regularly start afresh.

If it's a major problem, extensive debugging may be able to explain where any major impacts are coming from, but this is not trivial debugging as it involves lots of measuring, gathering data, adjusting what you're looking at based on what you find, etc... all while trying to not influence the very thing you're trying to find/measure.